# "long" package is breaking `tsc build`

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

Yarn installs `long` as a dependency for other modules.  It installs the "umd" version, which is apparently a CommonJS module.

I receive the following error:

```
node_modules/long/umd/index.d.ts:1:18 - error TS1479: The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will produce 'require' calls; however, the referenced file is an ECMAScript module and cannot be imported with 'require'. Consider writing a dynamic 'import("../index.js")' call instead.        

import Long from "../index.js";
```

Obviously, I can't just update the file as indicated.

Is there a way to force the typescript compiler to not use the `umd` version?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "<project>",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.x.x"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "<repo>",
  "author": "<author>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "build": "tsc && tsc-alias",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.7",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.0-dev.20230920"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "types": ["./elevenlabs-api.d.ts"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      ...
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

I've tried installing `long@4.0.0` explicitly (non-UMDversion) `long@5.2.3` has a `umd` subfolder.  The base package in `node_modules` is correct, but all the other package that depend on it create their own `node_modules` folder with the breaking version.

I've tried using the same versions of the top-level dependencies that works.  Same result: the breaking `long` version is installed anyway.

Comment: I was able to suppress the error with `"skipLibCheck": true` in tsconfig.json.

Comment: I bumped into the same issue. Did you ever figure this out without suppressing the error?

Comment: Nope.  Got it working, swept it under the rug and forgot about it :/

Comment: I have same issue, any update ?

Comment: There's a GH issue open here: https://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js/issues/109 and a fix proposed here: https://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js/pull/130